# Fail to call table.CalendarReturns with randomly generated xts

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I use `PerformanceAnalytics::table.CalendarReturns` to produce a table of calendar returns of a randomly generated `xts`.

```
library("xts")
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
set.seed(0)
n <- 150
data <- xts(100 + cumsum(rnorm(n, 0.03, 0.1)), Sys.Date() + (1:n))
ret <- Return.calculate(data,"log")
PerformanceAnalytics::table.CalendarReturns(ret)
```

For this code I get the following error:

```
Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

R and all packages are update to date. The following is my session info:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541 xts_0.9-7                     zoo_1.7-11                   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-29 tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the function, but if you give `ret` column names (e.g. `colnames(ret) <- "ret"`), you won't get the error.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that you need to (confusingly) use `geometric=FALSE` since you have log returns.  The code for that function says "if (geometric) use prod(1+ret)-1 else use sum(ret)"  For geometric returns, use arithmetic chaining; for arithmetic returns use geometric chaining.